# How do I use Async with array.map when rendering in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How would I go about running this async with ReactJS?

```
{array.map((content, index) => {
    const var = await asyncFunction(param)

    return(
        <div key={index} className="someClass">
            <h4 className="anotherClass">{var}</h4>
        </div>
    )
})}
```

Comment: You wouldn't, you should add another component, return the component from the map with a prop passed to it and do the fetch inside of that component

Comment: @talfreds could you by any chance show an example of this done?

Comment: @datamonkey It really depends on what `param` and `var` are in your above code. If `param` is not unique to the content of the array, then you shouldn't be trying to do it in the loop. You'll need to give a slightly more realistic example.

Comment: you can try suspense: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactsuspense

Comment: React.Suspense is, as of react 17, only used for code splitting. The docs linked above explicitly say data lodaing with Suspense is not supported today. It's experimental for React 18: https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to separate the async processing from the rendering (as of React 17, at least), and you have to use the promise directly, but can be done in a function, stored in a state variable, then rendered. That function can be called when the array changes using useEffect.

Example:

```
function MyComponent(array) {
  const [vars, setVars] = useState([]);

  function handleArrayChanged(newArray) {
    // note: no error handling, do this yourself as appropriate.
    Promise.all(array.map(var => asyncFunction(var)))
      .then((newVars) => setVars(newVars))
      .catch(error => { /* handle error */ });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    handleArrayChanged(array);
  }, [array]);

  return (
    <>
    {vars.map((var, index) => {
      return(
        <div key={index} className="someClass">
          <h4 className="anotherClass">{var}</h4>
        </div>
      )
    })}
  </>
}
```

Depending on exactly what asyncFunction does, you may want to break that async check out into its own component, as well, but that's subjective based on what asyncFunction does.

```
function MyComponent({element}) {
  const [var, setVar] = useState(undefined)

  function handleElementChanged(newElement) {
    asyncFunction(newElement)
      .then(newVar => setVar(newVar))
      .catch(error => { /* handle error */ });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    handleElementChanged(element);
  }, [element]);

  return (
    <div className="someClass">
      <h4 className="anotherClass">{var}</h4>
    </div>
  );
}

function MyList({array}) {
  return (
   <>
     {array.map(element, index) => (
       <MyComponent 
         key={index}
         element={element}
       />
     )}
   </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Note, I haven't tested this code, but it should be close.